# how to set x_0,y_0 (false easting / false northing) of LCC in basemap

Tags: matplotlib-basemap, pyproj

I'm using matplotlib-basemap with LCC projection.

after using .proj4string, I found x_0, y_0 in map data with default value

I want to set x_0, y_0 to 0.

but I can't find variable about false easting and false northing

how can I set x_0,y_0 value to 0?

https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html - no argument data about x_0, y_0

```py
>>> map_lcc=Basemap(width=8000000,height=8000000, rsphere=(6378206.4,6356583.8),
...             resolution='l',area_thresh=1000.0,projection='lcc',
...             lat_1=33,lat_2=45,lat_0=23,lon_0=-96)
>>> map_lcc.proj4string
```

```
'+a=6378206.4 +b=6356583.8 +y_0=4000000.0 +lon_0=-96.0 +proj=lcc +x_0=4000000.0 +units=m +lat_2=45.0 +lat_1=33.0 +lat_0=23.0 '
```

Comment: Basemap does not support the handling of true projection's grid coordinates. If you need the missing features, you can use `pyproj`.

Comment: thanks @swatchai , I tried it with pyproj and got an correct values.